# How to rename parent node?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm very new in Angularfire.
I created a Firebase parent node, with several other parents. Now I need to know how to rename the main parent node.

[image: a view of my database]

Comment: you cannot edit the key("name") only the value can be edited by double clicking it

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rename it easily within the console, but you can add a new node with the same content "Meeting with..." and delete the existing node.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Björn, Finally I found it.

```js
 $scope.addMeeting = function(){

          if($scope.meetingEditCheck){
            var key = $scope.editKey;            
            var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('users/' + firebaseUser.uid + '/meetings/' + key);
            newPostKey.update({
                'name': $scope.meetingEditName,
                'date': Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
            });
           }
```